# substring() method in a Palindrome

Tags: java, recursion, palindrome

In a well know recursion `isPalindrome` method

```
  public static boolean isPalindrome(String s){

        if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
                return true; 

        if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
            return isPalindrome(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));

            return false;
        }
 }
```

there is one line that I dont quite understand. If, for example we pass the string `anna` to the `isPalindrome method`, what does this line of code

```
return isPalindrome(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
```

do to the string when `s` has a value of `nn` ?

In my understanding number 1 (index `1`) is for second letter `n`, and `s.length()-1` is equal `2-1 = 1`, but not including that index position, so that must be index `0` ??

Does it return an empty string or something else ?

Comment: You can simply test that by printing `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the value of `s` is `nn`, as we step through the statements, this will happen:

- `s.length()` is 2, so the first `if` condition doesn't match
- `s.charAt(0)` is `n`, and `s.charAt(1)` is `n`, so the second `if` matches
- Return the result of `isPalindrome` with parameter `s.substring(1, 1)`, which is the text range from position 1 until before the position 1, in other words, an empty string
- In the recursive call with empty string as input, `isPalindrome` will match the first condition on length, and `return true`

For the record, this is a very inefficient way to check a palindrome in Java,
because `substring` creates new strings, which is slow.
A more efficient recursive solution is possible by adding start and end index parameters, and moving them inward, until their difference becomes 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

The `return isPalindrome(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));` will "loop" by sending the string value that you have without the first and last characters — or from the second till the second-last (a.k.a. penultimate). Then it will compare again that string; then it will "loop" again by using the same routine.

I think your "confusion" may lie in the fact that `s.length()` will return how many characters `s` have (counting naturally from `1`..`N`); but `s.substring(...)` works with indexes, and they start with `0` (not at `1`). In that "fashion", the last character will be the length minus one.

Example:

```
String example = "Five"; // ["F", "i", "v", "e"]
                         //   0    1    2    3    <--- indexes
                         // Length is four (it has 4 characters)
```

Comment: It compiles. But if the value 0 is send back again after  this line `(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1))`  has processed `nn`, how to be sure that those two letter are checked whether they are same ? Because that line  only sent `0`

Comment: True, I never expect any `for`, `while`, `do`-`while` loop, `if`es...(anything) without brackets. Answer updated!